# K8s Deploy Yaml with scaling replicas count on the fly

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, yaml, azure-aks, replicaset

How to upgrade an existing running deployment with yaml deployment file without changing the number of running replicas of that deployment?
So, I need to set the number of replicas on the fly without changing the yaml file.

It is like running kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml along with kubectl scale --replicas=3 both together, or in another wards to apply deployment yaml changes with keeping the numebr of running replicas the same as it is.

For example: I have a running deployment which already scaled its pods to 5 replicas, need to change deployment parameters within CD (like upgrade container image, change environment variabls, .. etc) without manualy check the #running pods and update the yaml with it, how can achieve this?

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Use the kubectl edit command

```
kubectl edit (RESOURCE/NAME | -f FILENAME)
E.g. kubectl edit deployment.apps/webapp-deployment
```

It will open an editor. You can update the value for number of replicas in the editor and save.

Refer the documentation section - Editing resources
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#editing-resources